# How to get selected grid rows?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got an application with this stack: ASP.NET Core MVC + React.JS

[Client view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeLXs.jpg)

There is an issue I've been faced with. I've got a file Patients.js which return to the router some HTML code.

Patients.js:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    Grid,
    Table,
    TableHeaderRow,
    TableSelection,
    TableColumnResizing
  } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';
import {
    SortingState,
    IntegratedSorting,
    SelectionState,
    IntegratedSelection
  } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BaseToolbar from '../Base/BaseToolbar.js'

import '../styles/patients.css';

const URL = '/api/patients';

const columns = [
    { name: 'id', title: 'ID' },
    { name: 'lastName', title: 'Last name' },
    { name: 'firstName', title: 'First name' },
    { name: 'middleName', title: 'Middle name' },
    { name: 'age', title: 'Age' }
];

const defaultColumnWidths = [
    { columnName: 'id', width: 100 },
    { columnName: 'lastName', width: 200 },
    { columnName: 'firstName', width: 200 },
    { columnName: 'middleName', width: 200 },
    { columnName: 'age', width: 100 }
];

let rows = [];
const Patients = () => {
    const [allPatients, setPatients] = useState([]);

    const getPatients = async () => {
        let params = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers()
        };
        const result = await fetch(URL, params);

        if (result.ok) {
            const patients =  await result.json();
            setPatients(patients);
            rows = patients;
            return patients;
        }

        return [];
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getPatients();
    }, []);

    const AddHandler = () => { alert("add"); };
    const EditHandler = () => { alert("edit"); };
    const RemoveHandler = () => { alert("remove"); };

    return (
        <div style={{width:'100%'}}>
            <div>
                <BaseToolbar
                    onAdd={AddHandler}
                    onEdit={EditHandler}
                    onRemove={RemoveHandler}
                ></BaseToolbar>
            </div>
            <div style={{border: '1px LightGrey solid'}}>
                <Grid
                    rows={rows}
                    columns={columns}
                >
                    <SelectionState
                        selection={allPatients}
                        onSelectionChange={setPatients}
                    />
                    <SortingState
                        defaultSorting={[{ columnName: 'id', direction: 'asc' }]}
                        columnExtensions={[{ columnName: 'age', sortingEnabled: false}]}
                    /> 
                    <IntegratedSorting />
                    <IntegratedSelection />
                    <Table />
                    <TableColumnResizing defaultColumnWidths={defaultColumnWidths} />
                    <TableHeaderRow showSortingControls />
                    <TableSelection showSelectAll />
                </Grid>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default Patients;
```

As you see there are some handlers. I wanna do some logic there, but how can I get the selected rows?

allPatients variable returns me ugly data. If I select the first row it returns me smth like that:

```
0: {id: 1, firstName: 'firstPatientFirstName', middleName: 'firstPatientMiddleName', lastName: 'firstPatientLastName', age: 22}
1: {id: 5, firstName: 'secondPatientFirstName', middleName: 'secondPatientMiddleName', lastName: 'secondPatientLastName', age: 22}
2: 0
```

I think the third item is the index of the selected row in this array. But this method is ugh. Are there any more beautiful methods?

[How can I use this at all?](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/reference/grid/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a solution. If anyone still needed it.
I've edited my Patients.js:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    Grid,
    Table,
    TableHeaderRow,
    TableSelection,
    TableColumnResizing
  } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';
import {
    SortingState,
    IntegratedSorting,
    SelectionState,
    IntegratedSelection
  } from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import BaseToolbar from '../Base/BaseToolbar.js'

import '../styles/patients.css';


class Patients extends React.Component {
    patients = [];
    baseApiUrl = '/api/patients';

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            grid: {
                selection: [],
                rows: [],
                columns: this.getColumns(),
                defaultColumnWidths: this.getColumnsWidth()
            }
        };

        this.getPatients();
    }
    

    getColumnsWidth() {
        return [
            { columnName: 'id', width: 100 },
            { columnName: 'lastName', width: 200 },
            { columnName: 'firstName', width: 200 },
            { columnName: 'middleName', width: 200 },
            { columnName: 'age', width: 100 }
        ];
    }

    getColumns() {
        return [
            { name: 'id', title: 'ID' },
            { name: 'lastName', title: 'Last name' },
            { name: 'firstName', title: 'First name' },
            { name: 'middleName', title: 'Middle name' },
            { name: 'age', title: 'Age' }
        ];
    }

    async getPatients() {
        let params = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers()
        };
        const result = await fetch(this.baseApiUrl, params);

        if (result.ok) {
            
            const patients = await result.json();

            this.setState(prevState => {
                let grid = Object.assign({}, prevState.grid);
                grid.rows = patients;

                return {grid};
            });

            return patients;
        }

        return [];
    }

    onToolbarAdd() {

    }

    onToolbarEdit() {

    }

    onToolbarRemove() {

    }

    onGridSelectionChange(me, selectedRowIds) {
        me.setState(prevState => {
            let grid = Object.assign({}, prevState.grid);
            grid.selection = selectedRowIds;

            return {grid};
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{width:'100%'}}>
                <button onClick={function() {
                    console.log("A");
                }}>asdf</button>
                <div>
                    <BaseToolbar
                        onAdd={this.onToolbarAdd}
                        onEdit={this.onToolbarEdit}
                        onRemove={this.onToolbarRemove}
                    ></BaseToolbar>
                </div>
                <div style={{border: '1px LightGrey solid'}}>
                    <Grid
                        rows={this.state.grid.rows}
                        columns={this.state.grid.columns}
                    >
                        <SelectionState
                            selection={this.state.grid.selection}
                            onSelectionChange={(selectedRowIds) => this.onGridSelectionChange(this, selectedRowIds) }
                        />
                        <SortingState
                            defaultSorting={[{ columnName: 'id', direction: 'asc' }]}
                            columnExtensions={[{ columnName: 'age', sortingEnabled: false }]}
                        /> 
                        <IntegratedSorting />
                        <IntegratedSelection />
                        <Table />
                        <TableColumnResizing defaultColumnWidths={this.state.grid.defaultColumnWidths} />
                        <TableHeaderRow showSortingControls />
                        <TableSelection />
                    </Grid>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

As you can see it was refactored by me. Function is gone to class and the main part is in `<onSelectionChange>` tag. I've passed selectedRowIds there and used onGridSelectionChange method, where class state changing.
Enjoy!